# PHASER - pressing shoot button to fire bullets crashes game

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

started doing some coding in Phaser and while building a small game we ran into a issue. Everytime we shoot the game crashes.
Below is the following code related to firing bullets from our character.

```
preload:
    game.load.image('bullets','http://examples.phaser.io/assets/bullets/bullet11.png');

var bullets;

create (){
bullets = game.add.group();
     bullets.enableBody = true;
     /*bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
     bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet');
     bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
     bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
     bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
     bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
     */

fireButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN);
}

update () {

   if (fireButton.isDown)
    {
        fireBullet();
    }

function fireBullet () {

    var text = game.add.text(400,200,'rrrrrrrr'); //used to debug collision
    bullets.create(player.x+40,player.y,'bullets');
    //bullets.body.velocity.x=+50;
}

}
```

the above

```
function firebullet()
```

currently works in firing a bullet (that does not move)

but once we add the below solution (used in other examples)

```
 bullets.body.velocity.x=+50;
```

the game crashes when we try to fire a bullet.

thanks in advance for any help. 
Sorry for the horrible indentation

Comment: Please post the error and any messages reported in your browser's console window. Also try to use your browser's JavaScript debugger to investigate the issue.

Comment: Also, are you aware that `.x=+50` and `.x+=50` are different things? I think you want `.x+=50` instead of `.x=+50`.

Comment: Take care that your computer is not the one taking the bullet! ;)

Comment: Hey Dai, yes I am aware of that and tried both to no Avail 
As for your other question the error i get is:
Access to Image at 'http://phaser.io/sandbox/assets/games/invaders/bullet.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

VM2640 phaser.min.js:20 Phaser.Loader - image[bullet]: error loading asset from URL assets/games/invaders/bullet.png

Comment: even though it says it cant access the image - if we remove the velocity code - it works fine (except the bullet doesnt move.)

Answer (score 0):

Phaser weapon class should solve your issue.
[See this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/weapon/single-bullet). It makes using weapons in game very easy. Also note that you can also change the no. of bullets allowed at a time instead of having 1 bullet fired at a time as shown in this example.